# Spring 3 + Tiles 2 form error

Tags: forms, spring, exception, casting, tiles

I am getting this error when i click submit on a form in Spring 3 + Tiles 2...i dont know but the other pages which are not form work fine...The code for that is :

Error 500--Internal Server Error
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebRequestDataBinder
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:754)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doBind(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:744)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:296)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:354)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:342)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:763)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:709)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:536)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)

---

```
package com.ultimatix.framework.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.ultimatix.framework.vo.Contact;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class ContactController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addContact(@ModelAttribute("command")Contact _objContact)
    {
        System.out.println(_objContact.toString());
        return new ModelAndView("welcome");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/contact")
    public ModelAndView showContacts()
    {   
        return new ModelAndView("contact", "command", new Contact());
    }
}
```

---

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 + Tiles 2.0 - Contact Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Contact Manager</h2>
<form:form method="post" commandName="command" action="addContact.do">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center"
        width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">First Name</td>
            <td width="70%"><form:input path="strFirstName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Last Name</td>
            <td width="70%"><form:input path="strLastName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Email</td>
            <td width="70%"><form:input path="strEmailId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Contact No.</td>
            <td width="70%"><form:input path="strContactNo" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Add Contact" /></td>
            <td width="70%"><input type="reset" value="Clear Details" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `@SessionAttributes` without model attribute names or types is supposed to do?